# Vim Sublist operations

Tags: regex, list, vim, echo, sublist

I'm trying to create a script what detects the number of different characters in a selection.
p.e.

```
a = 4  (the character "a" is 4 times in the selection)
b = 2
e = 10
\ = 2
```

etc.
To obtain this, I created a list with sublist like this:
`[['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['e', 1], ['\', 1]]`  --> etc
(a = the character // 1 = the number of times the character is found in the text)

What I don't know is:

- how to searchi in a sublist? p.e. can I search if there is an "e" or "\" in the list?
- when there is a match of "e" how can I add "1" to the number after the "e"?
  `[['e', 1]] --> [['e', 2]]`
- and how can I search in a sublist with regex and echo it in an echo command
  p.e. search [a-f] and obtain this output:

  a = 1
    b = 1
    e = 2

  c, d, f are not found in list and has to be skipped.

Btw...does anyone know where I can find a good documentation about sublists?
(I can't find much information about sublists in the vim docs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the right data structure is a Dictionary mapping the character to the number of occurrences, not a list.

```
let occurrences = { 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, '\': 1 }
```

You can check for containment via `has_key('a')`, and increment via `let occurrences['a'] += 1`. To print the results use

```
for char in keys(occurrences)
    echo char occurrences[char] "times"
endfor
```

And you can use the powerful `map()` and `filter()` functions on the Dictionary. For example, to only include characters a-f:

```
echo filter(copy(occurrences), 'v:key =~# "[a-f]"')
```

Read more at `:help Dictionary`.

Comment: thank you Ingo. Yes that resolves my problem. Have you seen also the 3rd part of my question? I want to decide which characters to include in output by userdialogue. p.e. if the user inserts [a-f] in userdialogue it has to echo only the chars from "a" to "f". Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: @remio: I've expanded my answer. Please read the help on `filter()` and `map()`; these are important functions, and at the core of the _functional programming_ approach that everybody is talking about.

Comment: Ingo, Thank you very much. Just if I need it... What would be the filter function if I don't want to search only for `a-f` but also for `2-9` and a comma (`,`). I tried to add \| after [a-f] but that didn't work.

Comment: @remio: `'v:key =~# "[a-f2-9,]"'` (this is a regular expression collection atom), or `'v:key =~# "[a-f]\\|[2-9]\\|,"'` (backslash needs to be double-escaped because it is contained in double quotes; that's the only ugliness with `filter()`.

Comment: btw, you can use ``get(myList, index, default)`` to avoid index/key errors. (e.g. ``get(myDict, 'e', 0)`` would return either myDict['e'] or 0, depending on whether myDict['e'] exists. Also a handy way to allow for default values. (``get(a:000,0,g:MyDefault)``)